# Expected &-ptr, found tuple while iterating over an array of tuples

Tags: rust

I have an array:

```
const adjacent: [(i8, i8); 8] = 
    [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1)];
```

This array represents all adjacent neighbors of a cell within a *ROW*x*COLUMN* grid. To iterate over this array to find all neighbors, I do

```
for k in adjacent.into_iter() {
    let (i, c) = (k.0, k.1);
    if let Some(a) = grid.get(r+i, j+c) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The second line seems like it could be substituted for K, but this causes an error if you write `for (i, c) in adjacency.into_iter() { ...`

```
error: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iterator>::Item == (_, _)`:
expected &-ptr
found tuple
```

what's going on here? Can someone explain why I cannot do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The solution

There is quite something going on there. First the working code:

```
for &(i, c) in &adjacent { }
```

More detailed explanation follows.

---

#### The Problem

Your iterator is spitting out items of the type `&(i8, i8)` which are references to the actual data. You tried to destructure it with the `(i, c)` pattern. This doesn't work because those are two different types; namely a reference to a tuple and a tuple. Hence, if you add the `&` to your pattern, the type of the pattern and the item match and the compiler can happily destructure it for you.

#### How to solve this on your own the next time

The full error message is:

```
<anon>:11:5: 11:42 error: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, (i8, i8)> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == (_, _)`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found tuple [E0271]
<anon>:11     for (i, c) in adjacent.into_iter() {}
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This error message could actually be improved, but nevertheless: Let's dig into it. The compiler says it can't resolve an actual type (on the left, `core::slice::Iter<'_, (i8, i8)>`) as another type, that was somehow "requested" (on the right, `<core::iter::Iterator>::Item == (_, _)`).

You "requested" an Iterator with the item type `(_, _)`, which makes sense because that's exactly what you wrote: `(i, c)`. And what about the type on the left? If we look it up [in the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) we can see that it implements the `Iterator` trait with the `type Item = &'a T`. We can ignore the explicit lifetime `'a` and just notice that it's a reference to the type parameter `T`. But we know what `T` is by looking at the error message: `core::slice::Iter<'_, (i8, i8)>`. So `T` is `(i8, i8)` and thus the item type of the iterator is `&(i8, i8)`.

#### About `IntoIterator` and for loops

You used an explicit `.into_iterator()` call on the array. It's understandable why you did that: `for _ in adjacent` fails with the message

```
the trait `core::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for the type `[(i8, i8); 8]`
```

This is confusing: Why wouldn't you be able to iterate over an array of size 8? Indeed, to understand it, you have to know about how `for` loops work.

The "thing" you want to iterate over has to either implement [`Iterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) directly or [`IntoIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). Most data structures (arrays, `Vec`, ...) don't implement `Iterator` directly, but `IntoIterator`. The `array` primitive does implement `IntoIterator`, too -- kinda. If we take a look at [the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#implementations), we can see that there are two implementations of `IntoIterator` for each array length:

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a [T; 8]
    type Item = &'a T

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut [T; 8]
    type Item = &'a mut T
```

Notice how this trait is not implemented for the array type directly, but for a reference to it. Also these implementations have a reference as the `Item` type. So why isn't `IntoIterator` implemented `for [T; 8]` directly? **Because we cannot move out of an array**.

To fix this we write `&adjacent` instead of `adjacent` -- a reference to the array. Then the compiler will find the correct implementation. Why does the manual `into_iterator` call work? Well... that's a whole different story, but in short: the `.` method call converts between value and reference types on it's own.

**TL;DR**: So if you have a data structure `adjacent` of some type (array, `Vec`, ...), you basically have three possibilities:

- `for _ in &adjacent`: You want to iterator over immutable references to the items. This is what you want most of the time!
- `for _ in &mut adjacent`: You want to iterator over mutable references in order to modify the items.
- `for _ in adjacent`: You want to take ownership of the items and thus make the data structure unusable afterwards. The least common option! Doesn't even work for some data structures.

Answer (score 4):

The error says it is expecting a pointer, so you have to use `&` in the pattern:

```
for &(i, c) in adjacent.into_iter() {
    let (i, c) = (k.0, k.1);
    if let Some(a) = grid.get(r+i, j+c) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

This specific `for` loop does not take ownership of the elements, it takes ownership of the references.

We can see a better error with the following, equivalent, code:

```
let mut it = adjacent.into_iter();
loop {
    match it.next() {
        Some((i, c)) => println!("{}, {}", i, c),
        None => break,
    }
}

src/main.rs:7:18: 7:24 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&(i8, i8)`,
    found `(_, _)`
(expected &-ptr,
    found tuple) [E0308]
src/main.rs:7             Some((i, c)) => println!("{}, {}", i, c),
                               ^~~~~~
```

Comment: It is not correct to say that the `for` loop does not take ownership; it's just `into_iter()`, when invoked on a fixed-size array, returns an iterator which yields references. It seems this happens because `into_iter()`, when called on a fixed-size array, returns a slice iterator - error messages say exactly that. I believe that fixed-size arrays can't be currently iterated by value because we don't have type-level integers yet, and without them it is very difficult to write the required `IntoIterator` implementation.

Comment: I added an answer with a more in-depth explanation, if anyone's interested :)