# Recursively visiting enums in a Hashmap

Tags: loops, enums, hashmap, iteration, rust

I modeled a filesystem-like structure with an enum, two structs and a BTreeMap, like this (simplified):

```
pub enum Item {
    Dir(Dir),
    File(File),
}

struct Dir {
    ...
    children: BTreeMap<String, Item>,
}

struct File {
    ...
}
```

Now I need to loop over a Dir and do some operation on every File. I tried this:

```
fn process(index: &Dir) {
    for (_, child) in index.children {
        match child {
            Item::File(mut f) => {
                let xyz = ...;
                f.do_something(xyz);
            },
            Item::Dir(d) => {
                process(&d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get:

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
       for (_, child) in index.children {
                         ^~~~~
```

I also tried

```
for (_, child) in index.children.iter() {
```

but then I get

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&Item`,
    found `Item`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `Item`) [E0308]
src/...  Item::File(mut a) => {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried several combinations:

```
for (_, child) in &(index.children)
for (_, child) in index.children.iter().as_ref()

match(child) { Item::File(&mut f) =>
match(child) { Item::File(ref mut f) =>
```

and so on, but couldn't find a way to make the borrow checker happy.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. Here is a working version with numbered changes:

```
fn process(index: &mut Dir) {
    //             ^^^-- #2
    for (_, child) in &mut index.children {
        //             ^^^-- #1
        match *child {
            //^-- #3
            Item::File(ref mut f) => {
                //     ^^^-- #4
                f.do_something();
            },
            Item::Dir(ref mut d) => {
                //    ^^^-- #4
                process(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Saying `for /* ... */ in index.children` tries to move `children` into the iteration. There are already [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836892/expected-ptr-found-tuple-while-iterating-over-an-array-of-tuples/33841530#33841530) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376286/using-moved-values-in-a-function/35378203) on SO explaining why that's the case. We want to iterate without consuming, but be able to mutate the values.
2. Because of (1.) the function also needs to have a *mutable* reference to the `Dir`
3. `child` is a mutable reference of type `&mut Item` (because that's what the iterator yields). The patterns in the match block (`Item::File(/* ... */)` for example) have the type `Item`. This is a type mismatch (your second compiler error). We can resolve that by dereferencing `child` with `*`.
4. So the `match` block matches on `Item`, but we do not actually own the item and can't move out of it. To prevent a move, we add the `ref` keyword. Now `f` and `d` are references and we avoided a move.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation in 1. is the reason I tried to use .iter() (because it returns references).

I found the manual extremely confusing on the whole &, &mut, ref and * and the places you can use them. It's very clear what they do when used in function arguments and calling parameters, but I would have never tried to use &mut after a for...in, or a * after match...